# Need help determining if a component is acceptable for use in a production design

Tags: pcb-design, component-selection, prototyping, production, certification

For the sake of not going too broad, I am only referring to [this single OLED LCD board](https://www.newegg.com/p/2A7-00D0-00094?item=9SIAAZM4K91701&nm_mc=knc-googleadwords&cm_mmc=knc-googleadwords-_-ec%20-%20test%20%26%20measurement-_-haoyishang-_-9SIAAZM4K91701&source=region) component from Newegg being used directly within a prototype device that I have designed. My end goal is to take this final prototype device to market in the U.S. with all necessary certifications.

As the title mentions, I mean *acceptable* in terms of being integrated out-of-the-box with my production version PCB (the rest of my electronics) and also not preventing the final product from being certifiable (UL, FCC, CE, etc.).

**In practice, do designers and industry integrate components like this into their production designs?** Why or why not would designers use this OLED display or similar, aside from cost?

Comment: If it meets the requirements of your design, those of the standards you need to comply with, and you can reliably purchase it at an acceptable price, then use it. Your previous question mentioned very small quantity -- in reality this means some serious compromises have to be made.

Comment: Depending on your "production volume", typically you would work directly with the manufacturer instead of a third-party reseller like Newegg. They can help you determine issues with regulatory approvals. If you are only making a couple dozen, the manufacturer may not be willing to help, so it's all on you to work with the regulatory bodies and have alternatives if it can't work.

Comment: @PeteW Yes, the first order or two would be a small batch since it would be a new concept entering the market. Order size would expect to increase after product validation within the market.

Comment: Quality, believability, reliability, data sheet accessibility, supply chain reliance, etc etc..

Comment: FYI EastRising are the OEM that make that particular display. There are actually not that many Chinese suppliers in the small display category, and you bump into most of them if you ever attend an international electronics trade show.

Answer (score 0):

I actually happened to use the same device for some products, they are attractive and cheap.

I never was able to find the actual display manufacturer and those can be found as modules on many websites (newsegg, taobao).

Given the manufacturer is a mystery, there is no way to know the actual production, stock, and if it is still being manufactured.

My guess is that this display might have been manufactured for a specific device (perhaps an old cellphone) that didn't sell well or never made it to market, perhaps a few 10s of thousands of those unused display made it to the "hacker" market.

Designing a product for the mass market with an "unknown" display might be risky, it may very well end up that this display is no longer available at some point which would cause you quite some trouble.

I've stopped using this display for this reason and I prefer to stick to well-known manufacturers or at least devices that the manufacturer is known, even if in my case we do not ship a lot of units, I do not want to have to go back redesigning a product because some parts become unavailable, especially a display as it would also require redesigning the enclosure and perhaps all the "UI".

If you have to replace the display and you've got remote firmware updates, you need to start to handle different hardware versions, adding to the complexity.

If it were to become unavailable, you wouldn't even be able to contact the manufacturer.

Personally, I wouldn't take the risk unless you can track down the actual manufacturer and make sure they can produce them.

I'd rather go with something like [that](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/orient-display/AOM12864A0-0-96WW/13150612).

Comment: Or, if you can, I'd just use a bog-standard 16x2 character LCD. Cheap, reliable, and you never have to worry about not being able to get one since they're so ubiquitous.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your perspective and speaking in detail from your personal experience. In practice, do designers, companies and even start-ups who develop production models try to stay away from complete boards like the one I linked or even breakout boards as well?

Comment: It really depends on the products. If it is low series very specific stuff and where cost isn't an issue, usually you prefer to use boards (like Linux systems) to cut down on dev cost. If it's a cost-sensitive mass product you will spend more $ on dev to reduce hardware cost and thus designing everything making sure you won't have components supply issue.

Comment: This is for example very true for all the RF like Bluetooth, you can either use a Bluetooth module that usually is more expensive and design your electronic around or use a Bluetooth chip, have better control, and design the RF, also spending money and time on RF certification and so forth. You can see some speakers using a Bluetooth module, but you won't see that in a cellphone. If your name is Bose, the Bluetooth will be a chip design, if your name is Xianhua super speaker it's probably gonna be a module.